# How can I compare two ecdfs for p-values from Kolmogorov Smirnov tests if the number of samples in the two tests are different?

Tags: r, p-value, computational-statistics, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

The plot below shows the ecdf of the p-values from to different statistics, let us identify the blue graph as vector x and the red graph as vector y. Now I execute a ks.test for x and y compare these vectors with a uni distribution in a small range.

```
ks.test(x[x<=0.2],function(x){punif(x,0.01,0.2)},alternative = "two.sided")
ks.test(y[y<=0.2],function(x){punif(x,0.01,0.2)},alternative = "two.sided")
```

Now I get better values for the blue-line but it's obviously that the red-line should be a better fit. If I watch closer to the values in x and y I get only 26 values in x and more than 1500 in y. So I think, the reason why the ks.test gives a better p-value for the blue-line depends on the low number of relevant points in x.

The values in x and y comes from a simulation. Schould I increase the number of simulated experiments?

[image: ecdf]

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the most straightforward solution to your problem is to match the number of simulated experiments in x and y.  You will tend to see lower p-values when N is higher because the test has more power and it is seldom the case that our data perfectly match the null hypothesis.

Comment: But I cant decide which elments I should use from y in the range [0,0.2]?

Comment: has someone any idea?

Comment: So can I compare the following tests? `len<-length(x[x<=0.2])
rb<-y[len]
length(y[y<=0.2])
ks.test(x[x<=0.2],function(x){punif(x,0.0,0.2)},alternative = "two.sided")
ks.test(y[1:len],function(x){punif(x,0.0,rb)},alternative = "two.sided")
`

Comment: Well... in principle you could... I guess.  It seems like a lot of data to throw away.  But since you're doing this over and over again over a lot of tests and building the ecdf as you go and you aren't really doing a statistical test to compare the two results... sure?  Why not?  Just in case there are sequential dependencies, I'd recommend that you call ks.test[y[sample(1:length(y),len)], function (x) {blahblah})

Comment: Yes, I simulate 10000 experiments, for each I do a calculation on two differnt statistics, $T_1$ and $T_2$ and I assume a distribution for this statistics. Under this assumption I calculated the p-values for each experiment for each statistic. After that, I like to compare the p-values in a small range, e.g. between [0,0.2]. But I dont repeat this process more then once, I dont realy get what you guess.